# import error: DLL load fail, paging file is too small for this application to complete (pyinstaller application)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, queue, pyinstaller

I converted python script to windows executable using pyinstaller. my python script has multiprocessing, queues and select socket module for socket communication. module that i used are pandas, manager(multiprocessing) for shared variables between different processes. after converting to exe, when I run it  I'm getting bellow error.

ImportError: DLL load failed. paging file is too small to complete this operation.
and getting this issue while importing pandas module in the code. but when run it in IDLE there is no issues. executing without any error.

what can be done to solve this, tried adding hidden import while creating the exe.